# Count Artikel that has same status

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot

I have this SELECT:

```
SELECT ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR, ADR_Adressen.Name, ADR_Adressen.Vorname, CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon, 
CRM_Status.StatusCRM, LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG, LAG_Artikel.Bezeichnung1 
FROM    ADR_Adressen 
LEFT JOIN  PRO_Auftraege ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR =  PRO_Auftraege.Kunde  
LEFT JOIN  CRM_Aufgaben ON PRO_Auftraege.AuftragNrPRO =  CRM_Aufgaben.AuftragNrPRO  
LEFT JOIN  CRM_Status ON CRM_Aufgaben.StatusCRM =  CRM_Status.StatusCRM  
LEFT JOIN  LAG_Artikel ON CRM_Aufgaben.ArtikelNrLAG =  LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG  
LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink ON ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR =  ADR_GruppenLink.AdressNrADR  
LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen ON ADR_GruppenLink.GruppeADR =  ADR_Gruppen.GruppeADR  
LEFT JOIN  CRM_AufgabenLink ON CRM_Aufgaben.AufgabenNrCRM =  CRM_AufgabenLink.AufgabenNrCRM
WHERE 
CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon >= { ts '2016-03-01 00:00:00'} 
AND CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon <= { ts '2016-03-31 00:00:00'} 
AND ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR = 10303 
GROUP BY ADR_Adressen.AdressNrADR,CRM_Status.StatusCRM, ADR_Adressen.Name, ADR_Adressen.Vorname,CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon, 
CRM_Status.Bezeichnung, LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG, LAG_Artikel.Bezeichnung1 
ORDER BY ADR_Adressen.Name,ADR_Adressen.Vorname,CRM_Aufgaben.TerminVon,LAG_Artikel.ArtikelNrLAG
```

[image]

With this i write a Report that Looks like this:

[image]

The Green parts is the StatusCRM field where i say when Status = 1 the "Anwesend" and so on.

Now i want to try to optimize my Report so that if the StatusCRM and ArtikelNrLAG is the same i want to make a X on the same line like i Show in the Picture below. In the Example downstairs i show how the motomed should look like.

[image]

Does someone know i could Change my SQL to make this work?

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but when LEFT JOIN put the right side table's conditions in the ON clause to get true left join behavior. (When in WHERE, you get regular inner join result.)

Comment: Also, I see the GROUP BY, but I find no aggregate functions. How come?

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for reply. I dont use GROUP BY i get 112 rows (duplicated) thats why i have GROUP BY. About the LEFT JOIN i dont understand what you mean :) Somehow i Need to Count how many rows where StatusCRM and AritklNrLAG is the same and use the TerminVon so i can write this out on the same line

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT DISTINCT` if you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: @jarlh didnt think about that, good solution. Thanks